# pygame_error[AttributeError: 'Cat' object has no attribute 'rect'(Pygame)](Crash) why?

Tags: python

How do I fix this error?
I use print examination it is execution, but when I use self.rect it will be error.
Now I try to use input() and a lot of thing, but now it also didnt work.
In the "def *init*:" I have to use self.rect but it didnt have error.
Who can help me?

```py
from turtle import up
import os
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import Color, QUIT, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, USEREVENT, USEREVENT
pygame.display.set_caption("666")
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
IMAGEWIDTH = 300
IMAGEHEIGHT = 200
FPS = 60

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
cat_png = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("F:\py\gamepy", "cat.png")).convert()

catx = 100
ballx = 240
class Cat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._in(self)
        self.image = cat_png
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2)
    def update(self):
            key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
                self.rect.y += 2              
            if key_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
                self.rect.y -= 2 

all_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
cat = Cat()
all_sprite.add(cat)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    all_sprite.update()
        
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(cat_png, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "f:\a.py", line 45, in <module> all_sprite.update() 
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 539, in update sprite.update(*args, **kwargs) 
File "f:\a.py", line 29, in update self.rect.y += 2 
AttributeError: 'Cat' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Comment: Add full error output to the question, just one line is not sufficient

Comment: all error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\a.py", line 45, in <module>
    all_sprite.update()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 539, in update
    sprite.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\a.py", line 29, in update
    self.rect.y += 2
AttributeError: 'Cat' object has no attribute 'rect'

Answer (score 0):

I think there are typos in constructor call, it should be:

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

but you have

```
def _init_(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite._in(self)
```

Comment: I fix this wrong but it also have thats error

Comment: @ivanking741245 there is another one, Please note double underscores in __init__(self) definition, it is important

Comment: if i use def __init__(self) and then my key_pressed will not have any reaction

Comment: @ivanking741245 but the program is now running without exceptions or syntax errors? If so, I think this question is solved, and it’s better to create another one, so people could help you with pygame key pressed issue

Comment: OP: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; and the purpose of posts here **is not** to get your code working, but to contribute **questions** to a Q&A database that can help others.